# Log4net on IIS7,5 or other logger?

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

I got question about log4net is it working on IIS 7,5?
I read lot of articles that says it doesnt support IIS 7.5 is it true?
Or maybe someone got better solution for logging in nhibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4Net is not related to IIS in any way.

All is needed for it to work is sufficient security permissions and appropriate configuration.